# Changing The Appearance of a Django Form Based on a Condition Before The Form Loads

Tags: django, django-forms

I am very new to Django, so please bear with me if my question seems naive.

How do I change values of a form based on a condition before the form loads?
For example, if there is a form checkbox field called "Admin", and the user is an admin, I would like to know how I could have that checkbox field checked before the form loads. Do I add this logic to the view calling the form or do I add this to the form class?

I am using Django 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check it in view before initializing form object.

```
if request.user.is_superuser:
  initial = {'checkboxfields_name':True}
else:
  initial = {'checkboxfields_name':False}

form = YourForm(request.POST, initial = initial) if request.method == 'POST' else YourForm(initial = initial)
```

something like that, i guess.

Comment: Or even `form = YourForm(request.POST or None, initial = initial)`

Comment: @karthikr If we're playing [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) `form = YourForm(request.POST or None, initial={'checkboxfields_name': request.user.is_superuser})` ;-)